# Dropzone js : Techical issue, Deleted file not working in mozila firefox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone js for development. There is specific Firefox browser issue. Kindly follow the below steps to reproduce the issue.

We are not directly uploading file(s) instead, we select file(s) and use the upload button to upload to the server.

## Steps to reproduce

1. Select the file(s) from the dropzone area.
2. Those file(s) were stored in memory until we clicked the submit button, then we physically removed them from our system.
3. After that, I submit the form, and we are not getting the "Server responded with 0 code" error message from dropzone. Because generally, dropzone give the same error in the "error" function, which is how we handle errors.

4. This issue works perfectly fine in Google Chrome, but in Mozilla Firefox, it is taking at least 4-5 min exactly for response "Server responded with 0 code".

We tried using many ways, like comma missing, code after return statement and so on but unfortunately didn't get any solutions.

Comment: I think deleting a file that you want to upload is probably going to end in tears anyway. It's not something I would worry about. It just seems that FireFox doesn't deal with the situation very well.

Comment: @phuzi Thanks for the reply, but it is working perfectly in google chrome as well as in our local system at when we run the project in Mozilla firefox.

Comment: _"but it is working perfectly in google chrome"_ That still doesn't mean it's a supported scenario, you just got lucky in Chrome. Personally I wouldn't waste time on this.

Comment: If the response status is 0 then there was some network or communication failure between the browser and the server.